# How do I know that the Flask application is ready to process the requests without actually polling it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, flask

During a smoke test, I want to ensure that a Flask application is handling correctly a few basic requests. This involves starting the Flask application asynchronously:

```
class TestSmoke(unittest.TestCase):
    @staticmethod
    def run_server():
        app.run(port=49201)

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.flaskProcess = multiprocessing.Process(target=TestSmoke.run_server)
        cls.flaskProcess.start()
```

and then run the tests which perform the requests with `requests` library.

If the code is left as is, the tests are often run *before* the server is actually started, which results in `ConnectionRefusedError`. To prevent this from happening, I appended the following code to `setUpClass`:

```
while True:
    try:
        requests.get("http://localhost:49201/", timeout=0.5)
        return
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        pass
```

While this works, it looks ugly. Given that the test case is in control of the Flask application, there should be a way for it to be notified once the application is ready to process the requests. Unfortunately, the closest thing I've found is [`got_first_request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.got_first_request), which doesn't help (unless once again I'm polling the server).

How is it possible to determine that the Flask application started and is ready to process the requests when running it asynchronously?

Comment: Found a solution? I'm trying to achieve the same thing.

Comment: @JohanBjäreholt: I haven't found any solution to that. If I remember well, I kept the polling. Another way would be to use a message queue or a similar interprocess communication channel in order for the server to send a readiness notification to the tests. I suppose that for most apps, this would be an overkill.